# launcher settings?

Tags: gnome-classic

Hi my name is Jim Simoni. I wish there was some way to relate to the desktop to the old desk top with menus so this transition would be easier. I like the old organisation in the menu bar. I had places, applications, system and others I have forgotten. I need the list to make the transfer to the new system. Can some one tell me how to look or get a list of all the organization menue it had?

My problem though is that I can not find any setting that control the launcher. The quide says in settings appearance there should be a slider that controls the size of the icons. I can not find it. I don't know if my theme makes it invisible? Can someone help I can't find it.

Jim

Comment: Duplicate of [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/65926)

Answer (score 1):

If you like the old style desktop you might install the gnome-session-fallback package via Ubuntu Software Center, but beware that this package isn't the Gnome 2.x desktop, but simply a fallback of Gnome 3.x.

if you wish to customize Unity (and not only the size of launcher's icons) you might install ubuntu tweak; in this case, you have to proceed as follows:

1. open a Terminal window and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:tualatrix/ppa
   sudo apt-get update -y
   sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-tweak
   ```
2. When the installation process will be ended, launch the System settings and you'll find the icon of ubuntu tweak.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the appearance settings the slider is at the bottom.[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. My appearance settings do not show the Launcher Icon Size slider. I tried the first suggested line in the terminal window. The last line of the answer is as follows:

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

The second line I typed in got the following response:

Comment: First it went and read through a hole bunch of packets and then it said Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6AF0E1940624A220
 Basically no public key available

Comment: When I typed the third line I got the following answer:        Need to get 983 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,010 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  ubuntu-tweak
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
so I am now stuck. Also I don't know how to write three lines of code without using the enter key. Dos had an editor one could use. I don't know what Ubuntu has. Any help would be appreciated. I could not find ubuntu-tweak in the software center either even though I found an advanced settings software.

Comment: Please Help I would like to have a little more control of the launcher